# Perl Doubts.. Coding doubts

Tags: regex, perl

- How Can a variable with a variable name be created ??  For example $$ref;
  here        `$ref="name1";  or $ref ="name2" ;`
- How can a singly quoted string be converted into a doubly quoted string..? For eg.
  '`Hello\n'; to "Hello\n";`
- If `quotemeta` is operated on a string.. can it be reverted back to its
  previous form..? For example        `"hello\\nWorld\\\$" to "hello\nWorld\$.`

Comment: Regarding "How can a singly quoted string be converted into a doubly quoted string": just use double-quotes in the first place.

Comment: @doubleDown I think it's more about "how can I convert uninterpolated string into interpolated string". Looks like a job for some kind of templating system. [String::Format](https://metacpan.org/module/String::Format) maybe? (Haven't tried it yet)

Comment: @doubleDown Would like to get some more input from OP though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How Can a variable with a variable name be created ?? For example $$ref;*

Using single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
my $variableName = '$$ref';
print $variableName;
```

This is not very common and most probably indicates a wrong design. Ask yourself why you need this.

> *How can a singly quoted string be converted into a doubly quoted
>   string..?*

This question makes no sense to me. A string is a string, doesn't matter if it was single or double quoted. Once created, you don't know how it was created. What are you trying to do?

If what you want is expand variables in an existing string, [the documentation is pretty clear about how to do it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings?).

> *If quotemeta is operated on a string.. can it be reverted back to its
>   previous form..?*

[`String::Unquotemeta`](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/String-Unquotemeta-0.1/lib/String/Unquotemeta.pm)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve in the end? It would be much easier to answer sensibly if you provided some context.

As of now, part 1 is *asking* to use a hash instead of plain variables, unless you have *strong* reasons not to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my %hash = ( name1 => 42, name2 => 3.14 );
my $key = (rand() < 0.5) ? "name1" : "name2";
print $hash{$key};
```

Comment: *"What are you trying to achieve in the end? It would be much easier to answer sensibly if you provided some context."* +1

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. That is called symbolic referencing and is not recommended because for security reasons. And it's hard to debug, too.
2. Yes.

   my $text = 'Hello\n';

   ( my $interpreted = $text ) =~ s{ \\n }{\n}gmsx;

   print "'$text'\n";

   print "'$interpreted'\n";